# VBScript echo equivalent in JavaScript for Macro Express Pro

Tags: javascript, vbscript, macros, internet-explorer-11

With the recent deprecation of VBScript in IE11, I need to convert all my code that I have as an external script in Macro Express Pro. I've tried using JScript, but the macro runs for about a second and does nothing. I decided to switch to HTA/HTML and have the code print within a window. I've converted all the VBScript to the JavaScript equivalents, but I'm stuck with `WScript.Echo`. Is there a JavaScript equivalent for this?

I have a variable named `%Variables%` in the "Save console output to:" box. With `WScript.Echo`, if I need to exit out of the script and go back to VBScript, I can use the code below:

```
If Opt = "" Then
   Wscript.Echo "EXIT"
   Wscript.Quit
End If
```

This will send "EXIT" to `%Variables%` so that it can be used by Macro Express Pro to terminate the macro completely.

Is there a JavaScript way of doing the exact same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to stop JavaScript execution you can always use `return` to exit the current function naturally, but that obviously won't work if you have nested functions.

Probably the next-best alternative would be to [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) an exception to stop execution.

As for "echo" you can use the global `console` object. For example:

```
console.log("hello world");
```

Edit:

For a 500 milisecond "sleep" use [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('hello');
}, 500);
```

Note that `setTimeout` will not block the process however like `sleep` does on some other platforms.

Comment: `console.log();` worked perfectly! Thanks. :) Now, what about `WScript.Sleep`? I can't use `setInterval` because it needs to call a function. I just want 500 milliseconds to pass before going on.

Comment: @Lou I updated my answer to show an example of delaying execution

Comment: I take it there is no other way to specify a delay in JavaScript than `setTimeout` or `setInterval`?

Comment: Also, my next question is what is the JavaScript of VBScript's `Err`? I can use `Err.Number`, `Err.Source`, and `Err.Description` to let me know what kind of error I'm running into in VBScript, but it doesn't work in JavaScript.

Comment: Right, those are the two built-in functions for delay in JavaScript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw